# python setuptools include files from parent directory

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following directory structure (pretty standard for a python distribution):

```
/some_dir
  /common
    file1.dat
    file2.dat
  /src
    pkg1/
      __init__.py
      stuff.py
    setup.py
```

What I want to achieve is package both `pkg1` and `common` into the same python egg. The `setup.py` file is pretty standard (auto discover packages) and `pkg1` is properly included, unfortunately I can't say the same about `common`. I tried many things, like `package_data`, `package_data_files`, `package_dir`, etc. Nothing seems to work. How can I achieve this?

I'm also not keen on keeping this structure, but I do need those files into a common directory, because I have to generate nodejs, python and java libraries that include them, thus moving the `common/` directory inside python is not an option.

Comment: The correct name is [`data_files`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data), not `package_data_files`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a **MANIFEST.in** file and set **include_package_data** to **True** to register all the files you want to bundle with your package.

https://setupy.info/ gives a pretty good overview of all the options you might need.

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work. MANIFEST.in need to be defined next to setup.py, and can't properly include directories/files from upper path (it works, but it's copied in a wrong location).